# Cannot change the sizes of subviews in a certain UIView

Tags: ios, swift, uiview

In a view controller, two UIViews are displayed up and down. They have the same widths and 20 pixels apart.

If I click a UIButton, the height of the upper view(viewUpper) should increase by 30 pixels; while the lower one(viewLower) decreases by the same amount. So far I made the views do as I want. The upper one expanded, and the lower one shrank.

Also, the y coordinate of viewLower increases by same amount as well, so that these two views keep the distance.

What makes the problem is that the subviews in the lower view do not change in the same way as the superview is done. The lower view has two subviews aligned up and down.

The upper subview(viewTitle) should keep its size. The lower subview(viewContent) must decrease by 30 pixels. I wrote the code the following code:

```
viewContent.frame.size.height -= 30
```

This one didn't work though. So I used for statement written below, which didn't work as well.

[image]

```
@IBAction func changeSize(sender: UIButton) {
    //d is a Bool variable to choose whether it's turn to shrink the viewLower or not
    if d{
        d = false

        viewUpper.frame.size.height += 30
        viewLower.frame.size.height -= 30
        viewLower.frame.origin.y += 30

        //do not work
        //viewContetnt.frame.size.height -= 30

        //I tried this code to change the subviews in the same way
        for views in viewLower.subviews {
            if views.frame.size.height > 30 {
                views.frame.size.height -= 30
            }
        }
    }
    else {
        d = true

        viewUpper.frame.size.height -= 30
        viewLower.frame.size.height += 30
        viewLower.frame.origin.y -= 30

        //do not work
        //viewContetnt.frame.size.height += 30

        //I tried this code to change the subviews in the same way
        for views in viewLower.subviews {
            if views.frame.size.height > 30 {
                views.frame.size.height += 30
            }
        }
    }
}

func changeWholeViewSize(view: UIView, f: CGFloat){
    for views in view.subviews {

        if view.frame.size.height > 40 {
            views.frame.size.height -= f
        }
        if(views.subviews.count > 0) {
            changeWholeViewSize(views, f: f)
        }
    }
}
```

How should I manage this problem? The only two ways I know do not help me.

Comment: In fact the viewContent has two UITableViews; I did not mention them

Comment: Did you add the views and set frames, or use constraints?

Comment: @Wain I did set constraints to every view to set layouts. But none of them fixes the sizes of the views; only how many pixels they are from one another.

Comment: So what is the purpose of you wanting to change the height? And specifically be 30?

Comment: The two tableviews display categories; the left one is for primary and the right one is for secondary. Every time both categories are chosen, one line should appear onto "viewUpper"; which will increase the size of the upper view.

Comment: I want the maximum number of lines in viewUpper would be 3. Then I need to know how to handle the size of the view as I want. I failed in this part.

Answer (score 0):

From what I understand, try this : (using constraints)

1)Set top, leading, trailing and height constraints to **viewUpper**.

[image]

2)Set leading, trailing, bottom constraints to **viewLower**.

3)Set vertical spacing between the two views, i.e, 20.

[image]

4)In **viewLower**, set top, leading, trailing and height constraints to **viewTitle**. For the other subviews here, just pin them to the top, bottom and sides(don't set the height).

[image]

[image]

5)Now, whenever you press the button, change the height constraint(heightConst, suppose) of the **viewUpper**, like this :

```
self.heightConst.constant = 130
self.view.setNeedsUpdateConstraints()
self.view.layoutIfNeeded()
```

Hope this helps you.

Comment: your answer doesn't actually say what the height constraint is set on or how it's configured. also, how would you use it on different size screens and things like that?

Comment: @Wain - I have edited my answer and added images for better understanding of what I meant, and yes this would hold true for all screen sizes.

Answer (score 0):

To solve your problem, you should use layoutSubviews(method of UIView).

This is my code:

This is ViewController.m:

```
#import "ViewController.h"
#import "LowerView.h"

@interface ViewController ()

@property UIView* viewUpper;
@property LowerView* viewLower;

@end

@implementation ViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad {
[super viewDidLoad];
// Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

float viewWidth = [UIScreen mainScreen].bounds.size.width - 40;
_viewUpper = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(20, 20, viewWidth, 200)];
_viewUpper.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];
[self.view addSubview:_viewUpper];

float lowerLocY = _viewUpper.frame.origin.y + _viewUpper.frame.size.height + 20;
_viewLower = [[LowerView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(20, lowerLocY, viewWidth, 300)];
_viewLower.backgroundColor = [UIColor blueColor];
[self.view addSubview:_viewLower];

UITapGestureRecognizer* tapGR = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(tapHandle)];
[_viewUpper addGestureRecognizer:tapGR];
}

-(void)tapHandle{
NSLog(@"tagGR actived");
float moveDistance = 30;
_viewUpper.frame = CGRectMake(_viewUpper.frame.origin.x, _viewUpper.frame.origin.y, _viewUpper.frame.size.width, _viewUpper.frame.size.height + moveDistance);
_viewLower.frame = CGRectMake(_viewLower.frame.origin.x, _viewLower.frame.origin.y + moveDistance, _viewLower.frame.size.width, _viewLower.frame.size.height - moveDistance);
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning {
[super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
// Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

@end
```

This is LowerView.m:

```
#import "LowerView.h"

@interface LowerView()

@property UIView* upView;
@property UIView* lowView;

@end

@implementation LowerView

-(id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame{
self = [super initWithFrame:frame];

_upView = [[UIView alloc] init];
_upView.backgroundColor = [UIColor greenColor];
[self addSubview:_upView];

_lowView = [[UIView alloc] init];
_lowView.backgroundColor = [UIColor yellowColor];
[self addSubview:_lowView];

return self;
}

-(void)layoutSubviews{
float padding = 5;
float viewWidth = self.frame.size.width - 2*padding;
_upView.frame = CGRectMake(padding, padding, viewWidth, 50);

float lowerLocY = _upView.frame.origin.y + _upView.frame.size.height + padding;
float lowViewHeight = self.frame.size.height-3*padding-_upView.frame.size.height;
_lowView.frame = CGRectMake(padding, lowerLocY, viewWidth, lowViewHeight);
}

@end
```

Hope it can help you.

Comment: This doesn't consider that OP is using constraints for layout